# в чем разница между двумя кодами

Tags: python

Первый код:

```
 if curDirection == 0:
    print(len(Snake[-1]))
    Snake[-1][0] -= speed
 elif curDirection == 1:
    Snake[-1][0] += speed
 elif curDirection == 2:
    Snake[-1][1] += speed
 elif curDirection == 3:
    Snake[-1][1] -= speed
```

Второй код:

```
if curDirection == 0:
    Upd = Snake[-1][:]
    Upd[0] -= speed
elif curDirection == 1:
    Upd = Snake[-1][:]
    Upd[0] += speed
elif curDirection == 2:
    Upd = Snake[-1][:]
    Upd[1] += speed
elif curDirection == 3:
    Upd = Snake[-1][:]
    Upd[1] = Upd[1] - speed

Snake.pop()
Snake.append(Upd)
```

Snake - deque() из list
После выполнения кусков кода Snake изменяется по-разному.. Почему?

Comment: прогнал у себя код для четырех направлений, работает идентично (в чем я особо и не сомневался), нужнен более детальный пример кода в вопросе - начальные данные и различные результаты. Сама логика вычислений для змейки вызывает вопросы по корректности (но вопрос был не об этом)

Comment: Вроде бы эффект должен быть одинаковый. Просто в первом куске значения меняются сразу на месте, а во втором делается копия верхнего массива, потом в ней что-то меняется, после чего оригинал выкидывается и добавляется эта изменённая копия. Разница мне кажется может быть от того, что вы по-разному заполняли коллекцию изначально и, возможно, у вас там где-то ссылки объектов друг на друга, а где-то нормальные копии.

Comment: Что-то вообще странное. Написал змейку. При замене строки
Snake.append(Snake[-1]) на Snake.append([Snake[-1][0], Snake[-1][1]])
змейка начинает работать, хотя если компарить значения в скобках отдает True...